# How to add icon to android popup menu?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, popup

I am developing sample Android application in which I am trying to display menu items in the actionbar using popup and I want to display overflow menu which contain icon . Please help me to solve these problem .
popup_menu.xml is

```
<menu xmlns:androclass="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >   


<item
android:id="@+id/login"
android:icon="@drawable/user_icon"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
android:title="@string/login"/>
<item
android:id="@+id/register"
android:icon="@drawable/call_icon"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
android:title="@string/register"/>
<item
android:id="@+id/track_order"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
android:icon="@drawable/user_icon"
android:title="@string/track_order"/>
<item
android:id="@+id/policies"
android:icon="@drawable/call_icon"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
android:title="@string/policies"/>
<item
android:id="@+id/faq"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
android:title="@string/faq"
android:icon="@drawable/share_icon"/>
<item
android:id="@+id/share_app"
android:title="@string/share_app"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
android:icon="@drawable/share_icon"/>
<item
android:id="@+id/rateApp"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
android:icon="@drawable/user_icon"
android:title="@string/rate_app"/>
<item
android:id="@+id/settings"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
android:icon="@drawable/user_icon"
android:title="@string/settings"/> </menu>
```

and following code to Open the Popup-Menu

```
View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.profile); 
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, menuItemView);
popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.account); popupMenu.show();
```

Comment: What you have tried.Please post the code

Comment: <item android:id="@+id/login"
                android:icon="@drawable/user_icon"
                app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
                android:title="@string/login"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/register"
                android:icon="@drawable/call_icon"
                app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
                android:title="@string/register"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/track_order"
                android:icon="@drawable/user_icon"
                app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
                android:title="@string/track_order"/>

Comment: i want to load different XML for different condition .

Comment: that is why i am using popup method instead of nested menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [This Post](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example) and change **poupup_menu.xml** file like :

```
<menu xmlns:androclass="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >   
<item  
    android:id="@+id/one"  
    android:title="One"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon1.png"/>  

<item  
    android:id="@+id/two"  
    android:title="Two"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon2.png"/>  

<item  
    android:id="@+id/three"  
    android:title="Three"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon3.png"/>  
</menu>
```

Comment: OK Please Edit your post and Post your menu XML code please!

Answer (score 0):

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:icon="@drawable/user_icon"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/login"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/register"
    android:icon="@drawable/call_icon"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/register"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/track_order"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/user_icon"
    android:title="@string/track_order"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/policies"
    android:icon="@drawable/call_icon"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/policies"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/faq"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/faq"
    android:icon="@drawable/share_icon"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/share_app"
    android:title="@string/share_app"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/share_icon"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/rateApp"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/user_icon"
    android:title="@string/rate_app"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/user_icon"
    android:title="@string/settings"/>
```

Comment: View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.profile);
                    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, menuItemView);
                    popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.account);
                    popupMenu.show();